# How to use runOnUiThread in a class?

Tags: android, android-handler

My code is designed to read a .txt file from a URL, and then display the text inside my textview. the problem is, I am using this code in a class. and getting this error- "cannot resolve method runOnUiThread". How do I fix this??

```
public class mydownloaderclass {

// this method is called from MainActivity
public static void checkForUpdates(Context context) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String path ="http://host.com/info.txt";
            URL u = null;
            try {
                u = new URL(path);
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.connect();
                InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
                final ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                in.read(buffer); // Read from Buffer.
                bo.write(buffer); // Write Into Buffer.

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
                        text.setText(bo.toString());
                        try {
                            bo.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }.start();
}
```

}

I tried using asynctask

```
 public class readtextfile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = "";
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://www.dropbox.com/myfile.txt");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String line = null;

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                //get lines
                result += line;
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: runOnUiThread is available in activity class so you have to use getActivity().runOnUiThread or YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread

Comment: can you post your error,which you are facing?

Comment: You have to call it on your activity instance.

Comment: cannot resolve getActivity().

Answer (score 2):

Create a Handler instead to execute statements on Main Thread like this

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
 handler.post(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            //Write your RUN on UI Runnable code here
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
            text.setText(bo.toString());
            try {
                 bo.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            } });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use AsyncTask, android makes this class specially for doing some task on a working thread(doInBackgroung()) and then update UI in onPostExecute() method.

Comment: You can write this code directly in activity. If you don't have activity than you couldn't update your UI also. If you want to keep it this way then pass your activity instance to your class constructor.

Comment: class A { 
public Activity activity;
public A(Activity activity){
this.activity = activity;
loadFromFile.start();
}
Thread loadFromFile = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { }
    }

Comment: I put my code in asynctask, I just want to execute the asynctask from my method, how do I do that? I am getting error "..cannot be referenced from a static context" . using  new `readtextfile().execute();`

Comment: make 'readtextfile' inner class in the activity class, and create one object in onCreate of activity and call execute on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a view context. It can be the activity context where the text view is defined. 
The runOnUiThread runs on the main looper so it required a UI context. 
For that You can define a member field in the class where the Thread is defined and set it in the constructor. Or if the thread is in the activity itself. then simply set the context field in OnCreate and use it in the thread.

Hope this helps. :) 
Let me know if this fixes it.